# Синхронизация процессов. Mutex. Как синхронизировать одинаковые .exe

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, синхронизация, процесс

Есть сервер:

```
    STARTUPINFO si;  
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    DWORD dwExitCode;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));  
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    if (!CreateProcess("C:\\Users\\Артем\\Documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\Writer\\Debug\\Writer.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        cout << GetLastError();
        _getch();
        return -1;
    }
    Sleep(10);
    cout << "Process 1: ";
    while (GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode) != 0 && dwExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        cout << *((LPSTR)lpFileMap);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        Sleep(100);
    }
```

Который создает процесс клиента и получает из FileMapping символ, который был введен в Клиенте.

Клиент:

```
WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
    while (true) {
        chr = _getch();
        if (chr == '1') {
            *((LPSTR)lpFileMap) = '+';
            ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        }
        if (chr == '2') {
            *((LPSTR)lpFileMap) = '-';
            ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        }
        if (chr == '3') {
            *((LPSTR)lpFileMap) = ' ';
            ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
            WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);

            while ((chr = _getch()) != '\r') {
                *((LPSTR)lpFileMap) = chr;
                ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
                WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
                *((LPSTR)lpFileMap) = '\0';
            }
            break;
        }
        Sleep(10);
        *((LPSTR)lpFileMap) = '\0';
        if(chr > '0' && chr < '4') WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
    }
```

При вводе 1 - передает символ +, при вводе 2 - символ -, при вводе 3 - сообщение о завершении процесса.

Вопрос: как мне запустить несколько одинаковых процессов клиента и синхронизировать их? Например пользователь вводит с консоли кол-во процессов клиента, сервер их создает, и поочередно из каждого процесса получает сообщение. Т.е. первый процесс отправил +, сервер принял и перешел ко второму, второй отправил -, сервер принял и перешел к первому и так далее.

Answer (score 3):

Это не просто и к классическому мьютексу не имеет никакого отношения, однако  Майкрософт придумал особые. именованные объекты. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684123(v=vs.85).aspx

Один процесс создает и владеет таковым, в то время как другие могут получить к нему доступ по имени.

Эта программа создает мьютекс. Это оборачивается успехом даже если такой объект уже существует.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

// This process creates the mutex object.

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hMutex; 

    hMutex = CreateMutex( 
        NULL,                        // default security descriptor
        FALSE,                       // mutex not owned
        TEXT("NameOfMutexObject"));  // object name

    if (hMutex == NULL) 
        printf("CreateMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError() ); 
    else 
        if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS ) 
            printf("CreateMutex opened an existing mutex\n"); 
        else printf("CreateMutex created a new mutex.\n");

    // Keep this process around until the second process is run
    _getch();

    CloseHandle(hMutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Эта программа открывает существующий мьютекс с помощью функции OpenMutex, которая возвращает состояние неудачи, если объект не найден. Полный доступ необходим для операций ожидания.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// This process opens a handle to a mutex created by another process.

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hMutex; 

    hMutex = OpenMutex( 
        MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,            // request full access
        FALSE,                       // handle not inheritable
        TEXT("NameOfMutexObject"));  // object name

    if (hMutex == NULL) 
        printf("OpenMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError() );
    else printf("OpenMutex successfully opened the mutex.\n");

    CloseHandle(hMutex);

    return 0;
}
```